# No constants generated by T4MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Why no constant strings in T4MVC generated code? My guess would be compilation-time copying of constant values...

But adding constants to the generated code would allow T4MVC generated stuff to be used in attributes.

I think about something like this:

insert @line 400:

```
        public const String ControllerNameCONST = @"<#=controller.ClassName #>";
```

insert @line 445:

```
        [<#= GeneratedCode #>, DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public static class ActionNamesCONST {
<#foreach (var method in controller.ActionMethodsWithUniqueNames) { #>
<#  if (UseLowercaseRoutes) { #>
            public const string <#=method.ActionName #> =     (<#=method.ActionNameValueExpression #>).ToLowerInvariant();
<#  } else { #>
            public const string <#=method.ActionName #> =     <#=method.ActionNameValueExpression #>;
<#  }
} #>
        }
```

So someone could use it like this:

```
[SomeAttribute(HomeController.ControllerNameCONST)]
//instead of 
[SomeAttribute("Home")]
//or
[SomeAttribute(HomeController.ActionNamesCONST.SomeAction)]
//instead of 
[SomeAttribute("SomeAction")]
```

Edit: used it as an autocomplete attribute on a model, so the "target" controller and action can be specified on the model. Although could rework the autocomplete attribute to take an ActionResult as parameter instead of controller+action names...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update (12/7/2011): this issue is now fixed (in 2.6.65). See http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7177.

---

T4MVC does generate many constants. e.g.

For the controller name: `MVC.Home.Name`

For the action names: `MVC.Home.ActionNames.About`

For the view names: `MVC.Home.Views.About`

Comment: Yes, I know, but those are readonly "constants", not C# "const". So can't use them in an attribute, because you get a compile time error: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

Comment: Ah I see. Right it doesn't do that today. Tough part is that it couldn't be accessed as MVC.* like the rest of what T4MVC generates.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, it would be extremely useful for folks doing history management server side for the MVC.Controller.Name to be a C# const. That way they could be used inside switch statements in redirecting logic.